GCC makefile doesn't output elf file
I have the following makefile and it keeps failing with an error 1, no such file or directory, when it tries to load CanbusTest,elf - what am I doing wrong as it seems like everything is as it should, but apparently not lol
# makefile for project for testing eval board for ARM Coretex processor

PART = LM3S8962

# Tool chain

CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc --specs=nosys.specs -ffreestanding -nostdlib
OBJCOPY = arm-none-eabi-objcopy

# Pass to the Assember

AFLAGS=-mthumb         \
       -mcpu=cortex-m3 \
       -MD

# Project name

PROJECT = CanbusTest

# Source Files

SRCDIR = venv
INCDIR = venv/driverlib
INCDRV = venv/drivers
INCLDS = venv/inc
OBJDIR = venv/build

SRCS =  $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
#        $(SRCDIR)/sysctl.c

# Object Files

OBJS =  $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.c, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SRCS))


# Include directories
INCLUDES = -I$(INCDIR) -I$(INCDRV) -I$(INCLDS)

# output directory

OUT_DIR = buildFinal

# Compiler Flags

CFLAGS = -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MD -std=c99 -Wall  -pedantic $(INCLUDES) -v

# Linker Flags

LDFLAGS = -T linkerScript.ld -Wl,-Map=output.map,-verbose -nostartfiles

# $ make -rp 2>&1 | grep PROGRAMS_TO_CREATE
# PROGRAMS_TO_CREATE := copy.elf copy.dump copy.bin copy.hex copy.mem copy.coe sec_soft.elf sec_soft.dump sec_soft.bin sec_soft.hex sec_soft.mem sec_soft.coe

# Default Target

TARGET = $(OUT_DIR)/CanbusTest.elf

all: $(TARGET)

# Linking

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $@ $(OBJDIR)/CanbusTest.bin

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# Output Files
clean:
    rm -rf $(OUT_DIR)/*.o $(OUT_DIR)/CanbusTest.bin output.map

The directory structure is as follows:
venv
|_ build 
|_ buildFinal
|_ driverLib (subdirectory with header files)
|_ drivers (contains the h file for the OLED display on eval board
|_ inc (includes for hardware specific eval board

(source files here - basically, hello.c - used for testing compilation)
The makefile output is as follows:
==================================================
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-specs=nosys.specs' '-ffreestanding' '-nostdlib' '-mcpu=cortex-m3' '-mthumb' '-Os' '-ffunction-sections' '-fdata-sections' '-MD' '-std=c99' '-Wall' '-Wpedantic' '-I' 'venv/driverlib' '-I' 'venv/drivers' '-I' 'venv/inc' '-v' '-T' 'linkerScript.ld' '-nostartfiles' '-o' 'buildFinal/CanbusTest.elf' '-mfloat-abi=soft' '-mlibarch=armv7-m' '-march=armv7-m'
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary buildFinal/CanbusTest.elf venv/build/CanbusTest.bin
arm-none-eabi-objcopy: 'buildFinal/CanbusTest.elf': No such file
make: *** [buildFinal/CanbusTest.elf] Error 1


Is $(OUT_DIR) pre-made? There's no target to create it. Please edit your question and post the output of your make command

That can't be the output of running make; we would expect to see the $(CC) command executed before the $(OBJCOPY). This question would be much easier for us to answer if you provided enough information in your question for us to reproduce the problem locally. Can you update your question to include a [mcve]?

Your linking command has no inputs so you are not really making any elf files. make should've printed that command (somewhere above COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS)
